# Modifying Android source code

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-activity, android-build

I am absolutely new to Android. As a research curricular project, I want to make some changes in Android's activity manager's source code. I have downloaded the source code from [here](http://source.android.com) and built it for emulator. Now, to start with, I want to do some very simple things e.g. adding print statements to the module that I want to modify. This is just to make sure that my changes are actually showing effect. But how can I

1. See the changes I made. In this case, where can I see words/sentences printed by my print statements?
2. Even if I make such small change, do I need to build entire code base again using "make" command? Cant I just compile that particular class or file? I tried "mmm" and "mm" but they dont seem to be working. One says "nothing to build" even if I introduce syntax error and other says "no android.mk file found"
3. Can I add my own method to the ActivityManager class?

Thank you...

Comment: See "Setting up ccache" at the following link to speed up re-builds: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: "Can I add my own method to the ActivityManager class?" -> Yes. Modify the source file and build.

Comment: What kind of print statements are you talking about? Are you modifying native (C/C++) or Java code? For Java code you can use the Log utility and you can see that in the logcat.

Comment: u can add Log("string","your message"); or System.out.println(""); as in java , these two will display output on your logcat and u can see them using filter,otherwise u can add a toast message that pops up a message on your screen.

Comment: Thanks Leco, they are java statements. I have setup ccache but wanted to know if I can build just one class. @Arju: I am not writing app so will I be able to construct toast msgs? Also, where can I see logcat? Will it be inside emulator?

Comment: No, you need to connect with a command line, for example:"adb -s emulator-5554 logcat" would give you the logs taken from emulator-5554